# Why getRecordNotifyChange doesn't refresh the Lightning Page when record is changed?

Tags: lightning-web-components, record-type, get-record-notify-change

Assuming we have custom object `Test__c` with custom picklist field and two record types.

Custom LWC component with the following html

```
<template>
    Status: {status} 
</template>
```

and js

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecordNotifyChange } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import updateByApex from '@salesforce/apex/TestCont.updateByApex'

export default class Status extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
    status;

    async connectedCallback() {
        await updateByApex({recordId: this.recordId, objectApiName: this.objectApiName}).then(data => {
            this.status = data;
        })
        getRecordNotifyChange([{recordId: this.recordId}]);
    }
}
```

and JS meta file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>53.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

and the controller

```
public with sharing class TestCont {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String updateByApex(Id recordId) {
        Test__c rec = [SELECT Name, Id__c, Status__c FROM Test__c WHERE Id = :recordId];
        String newStatus = 'Complete';
        if (newStatus != rec.Status__c) {
            rec.Status__c = newStatus;
            rec.RecordTypeId =  '0121x000003GNZg';
            update rec;
        }
        return newStatus;
    }
}
```

and the flexi page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlexiPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <name>header</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <itemInstances>
            <componentInstance>
                <componentName>status</componentName>
                <identifier>c_status1</identifier>
            </componentInstance>
        </itemInstances>
        <name>main</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <itemInstances>
            <componentInstance>
                <componentName>complete</componentName>
                <identifier>c_complete1</identifier>
            </componentInstance>
        </itemInstances>
        <name>Facet-a4827d40-0b00-4f9a-b4fb-a98ca5c45fcf</name>
        <type>Facet</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <itemInstances>
            <componentInstance>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>active</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>body</name>
                    <value>Facet-a4827d40-0b00-4f9a-b4fb-a98ca5c45fcf</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>title</name>
                    <value>Standard.Tab.relatedLists</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentName>flexipage:tab</componentName>
                <identifier>flexipage_tab1</identifier>
            </componentInstance>
        </itemInstances>
        <name>Facet-5e5b9343-ed49-4a39-93c4-208ac499c95a</name>
        <type>Facet</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <itemInstances>
            <componentInstance>
                <componentName>incomplete</componentName>
                <identifier>c_incomplete1</identifier>
            </componentInstance>
        </itemInstances>
        <name>Facet-mujkkd20p</name>
        <type>Facet</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <itemInstances>
            <componentInstance>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>active</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>body</name>
                    <value>Facet-mujkkd20p</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>title</name>
                    <value>Standard.Tab.relatedLists</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentName>flexipage:tab</componentName>
                <identifier>flexipage_tab3</identifier>
            </componentInstance>
        </itemInstances>
        <name>Facet-91ev4xk6baa</name>
        <type>Facet</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <itemInstances>
            <componentInstance>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>tabs</name>
                    <value>Facet-5e5b9343-ed49-4a39-93c4-208ac499c95a</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentName>flexipage:tabset</componentName>
                <identifier>flexipage_tabset1</identifier>
                <visibilityRule>
                    <criteria>
                        <leftValue>{!Record.Status__c}</leftValue>
                        <operator>NE</operator>
                        <rightValue>Requested</rightValue>
                    </criteria>
                </visibilityRule>
            </componentInstance>
        </itemInstances>
        <itemInstances>
            <componentInstance>
                <componentInstanceProperties>
                    <name>tabs</name>
                    <value>Facet-91ev4xk6baa</value>
                </componentInstanceProperties>
                <componentName>flexipage:tabset</componentName>
                <identifier>flexipage_tabset2</identifier>
                <visibilityRule>
                    <criteria>
                        <leftValue>{!Record.Status__c}</leftValue>
                        <operator>EQUAL</operator>
                        <rightValue>Requested</rightValue>
                    </criteria>
                </visibilityRule>
            </componentInstance>
        </itemInstances>
        <name>sidebar</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>
    <masterLabel>Test</masterLabel>
    <sobjectType>test__c</sobjectType>
    <template>
        <name>flexipage:recordHomeTemplateDesktop</name>
        <properties>
            <name>enablePageActionConfig</name>
            <value>false</value>
        </properties>
    </template>
    <type>RecordPage</type>
</FlexiPage>
```

Also `incomplete` LWC component

```
<template>
    Incomplete
</template>
```

js

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Incomplete extends LightningElement {}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>53.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Also `complete` LWC component

```
<template>
    Complete
</template>
```

js

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Complete extends LightningElement {}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>53.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

The flexipage has right side bar with two components, one is designed to display when status is requested and another when status is different than requested.

On main component there is a pull to external system to grab the actual data change and update the status value.

Once the value is retrieved, it is updated in Test object and the retrieved data is displayed. I expected `getRecordNotifyChange([{recordId: this.recordId}]);` to grab this data change and update the right sidebar component to display appropriate component. However, it doesn't work. When there is no record types on the object, it works. When there is a standard record detail component, it is refreshed. However, my clients require standard record detail component to be removed from the flexi page.

Is there a way to achieve the desired functionality? Why `getRecordNotifyChange` doesn't work?

Comment: Hi Patlatus, How are you fetching the record in your right sidebar component?

Comment: I am not fetching any records in right sidebar component. I just display different components based on record attribute

Comment: You need to call the getRecord for records that you are updating, then only your component know that records are updated and it will call the getRecord wired adaptor again.

Comment: Can you update the code sample to show us how you're getting the status information for your right component ?

Comment: I have flexi page with three components. The left component updates the record on load. The right components refresh if the record is updated not on load. I have shared all the code to replicate the issue

Comment: @RahulGawale if calling getRecord is required, why does it work without calling getRecord when the record changes, for example, on button click? I have described very specific problem which reproduces under specific condition and I don't think calling getRecord helps or is needed in this case